# elasticbeanstalk ruby on rails assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new to Ruby on Rails. When I run my rails server on development mode locally, it works fine. I tried deploying to elastic beanstalk (on development mode) but for some reason the assets can't be found. Are there any configurations I need to do in the development.rb or config.yml files?

Comment: Can you paste the log which is saying `asset not found `or something?

Comment: Can you paste the log which is saying `asset not found `or something?

Comment: It's just an error I see in the browser console. I get an error saying that its 404 not found error when referencing a CSS/JS file.

Comment: make sure your assets are committed and not gitignored

Comment: Do I simply run "rake assets:precompile", commit the assets, then upload the zip? I am using the GUI and not command line interface.

Comment: `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`